# how to use a foreach loop in AutoMapper

Tags: c#

I am finding it difficult to Map from my data source to destination using AutoMapper. I have a source class containing a list of object. Now I want to map that list to a single class using a foreach to iterate the throw the list in order to populate the class using Automapper.

```
public class Source
{
  public List<StudentName> studentName {get; set;} 
}
public class StudentName
{
   public string Name { get; set;}
}

public class Destination
{
  public string FirstName { get; set;} 
}


 public List<Destination> GetStud(Source source)
 {               
     MapperConfigurationExpression cfg = new MapperConfigurationExpression();
     cfg.ValidateInlineMaps = false;
     cfg.CreateMap<Source,  Destination>();
     MapperConfiguration mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg);
     IMapper mapper = new Mapper(mapperConfig);


     var viewModel= new List<Destination>();

     // enter code here
     foreach (var item in source.studentName)
     {
         var destination = new Destination();    
         destination.FirstName = item.Name;                   

         destination = mapper.Map<Destination>(item);

         viewModel.Add(destination);

         var man = 0;
     }

     return viewModel;

}
```

This method i have try gives me the following error
Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type
For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters

Comment: The source and destination classes are totally different. You must indicate the correspondence of properties to be mapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must assign the properties to be mapped. It is not necessary to do the foreach, do the mapping to List:

```
public List<Destination> GetStud(Source source)
{  
    MapperConfigurationExpression cfg = new MapperConfigurationExpression();
    cfg.ValidateInlineMaps = false;
    cfg.CreateMap<StudentName,  Destination>()
       .ForMember(a=> a.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(itm=> itm.Name));

    MapperConfiguration mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg);
    IMapper mapper = new Mapper(mapperConfig);      

    var viewModel = mapper.Map<List<Destination>>(source.studentName);

    return viewModel;
}
```

Comment: Hy asd could you elaborate what src is

Comment: Hi @Seth, src is your source variable. I modified the code ;)